# Hermes JMS cannot connect to Websphere MQ 7.1 (2035 error)

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to Websphere MQ 7.1 with Hermes JMS but I am not able to. I have followed their giude, loaded all the jars without problems, set the plugin, set all the variables (hostname, port, transportType, queuemanager), checked the box at the bottom that says user and typed the username and password and after confirming I tried to discover however I get the following message back:

> com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:233)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:553)     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:593)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.(StoredManagedConnection.java:95)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:198)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:882)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:770)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:719)
>     at
>   com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:175)
>     at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.(MQQueueManager.java:647)    at
>   hermes.ext.mq.MQSeriesAdmin.getQueueManager(MQSeriesAdmin.java:107)
>     at
>   hermes.ext.mq.MQSeriesAdmin.discoverDestinationConfigs(MQSeriesAdmin.java:280)
>     at
>   hermes.impl.HermesAdminAdapter.discoverDestinationConfigs(HermesAdminAdapter.java:82)
>     at
>   hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.discoverDestinationConfigs(DefaultHermesImpl.java:1126)
>     at
>   hermes.browser.tasks.DiscoverDestinationsTask.invoke(DiscoverDestinationsTask.java:77)
>     at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)   at
>   hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

After a few hours of trial and error and research on the net, it seems that the issue is that it cannot connect due to bad authorization however I am able to connect using Java code (Using same lib MQQueueConnectionFactory) and I am also able to connect using QueueZee with the exact same libraries, get a list of all queues and browse them so I know user authorization issues should not be the problem.

I am running Hermes JMS 1.14 and I tried using both Java 1.6.0_33 and 1.7.0_5. Websphere MQ is running on version 7.1.0.0 and the libraries were gotten from this installation on a remote server.

I tried setting the channel variable to SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN which is what I used in QueueZee to get it to work but still the same issue.

Has anybody seen this issue before and hopefully can shed some light in the situation?

Answer (score 1):

At V7.1 the new CHLAUTH rules shut off access to all SYSTEM.* channels except SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN by default and do not allow any administrative access on any SVRCONN channel by default.  In order to diagnose this it would be necessary to know what channel was used, the CHLAUTH rules that are set, the channel definition (in particular, the MCAUSER value) and whether the ID used is in the mqm group.

You didn't mention whether the QueueZee setup was also to a V7.1 QMgr or this one in particular.  Taking a wild guess, I'd say that CHLAUTH rules are enabled and that the SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN channel is disabled at this point.  Recommended steps are to define a new channel whose name doesn't start with SYSTEM. and make sure the ID used is not in the mqm group but is authorized as a non-admin ID.

Alternatively, an ID in the mqm group can be used but you'd have to define a CHLAUTH rule to allow it to work.  For example, the default CHLAUTH rule uses `CHANNEL(*) BLOCKUSER(*MQADMIN)` and you could change that to `CHANNEL(THE.NEW.CHL.NAME) BLOCKUSER('nobody')`.  The new rule would be more specific than the old rule and thus take precedence on your channel. It tells the QMgr to block the user ID 'nobody' but omits any  mention of *MQADMIN.  Since 'nobody' doesn't have access anyway but since *MQADMIN is not mentioned (and thus not blocked by thei rule) the effect of the rule is to allow admins on this channel.

As a quick, dirty and temporary measure, you can also `ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)` to get the same behavior as in v7.0 and earlier QMgrs.  Be aware though that this allows anonymous remote admin and remote code execution using the mqm user ID.  That's why the default settings were changed.  Now you must explicitly provision remote admin access if you need it.

For more on this topic, I recommend the [Securing Your QMgr](https://t-rob.net/links/) presentation from the IMPACT conference.

Note that the password the app sends in is not checked by the QMgr.  The field exists so that channel exits can validate the password against AD, LDAP, etc.  Without such an exit, the password is ignored.  The user ID passed in by the client is either accepted at face value or modified by the channel's MCAUSER or by CHLAUTH rules.

Finally, when having authorization problems the easiest way to diagnose is to `ALTER QMGR AUTHOREV(ENABLED)` and then use [SupportPac MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P) to decode the PCF messages in WMQ Explorer.  The auths errors end up in the QMgr Event queue.  Each message tells you the object that failed auths, the API call made against that object, the options of the call and the ID that made the call.  Often we find the ID making the call isn't the one we wanted or that the program is using options it isn't authorized for so this can be extremely helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I used QueueZee I used it towards the exact same channel and user (and same queue manager and server) without any problems and I also did disable CHLAUTH as you mentioned above however that did not help and the issue still occurs.

I am starting to think that this is an issue in Hermes JMS itself.

Comment: If QueueZee can use the channel then it's the ID being passed in.  You can temporarily set the channel's MCAUSER to a value that will allow the connection.  However, enabling authorization events and using [MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P) or [MH05](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMH05) or one of the other event display tools from the [SupportPacs page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) will make the security issues practically diagnose themselves. The long term answer ends up with CHLAUTH enabled and setting MCAUSER from the QMgr rather than from the client.

Comment: Thanks again but I'd rather know what the issue is in then first place. I'll try at some point to see if MQExplorer can tell me why this is happening.

Comment: So you will enable authorization events and use MS0P or MH05 to parse them?  If so, post the results and it will be possible to reply with specific config instructions.

Comment: Do I need to enable authorization? Unfortunately this is an MQ which I cannot mess with much as we use it for testing. CHLAUTH is disabled on it since it is just a test machine however besides trying to check MQ Explorer and possibly adding plugins to it I am limited on changes to MQ configuration itself.

Comment: Enabling authorization **events** is not the same as enabling CHLAUTH. Doing `ALTER QMGR(AUTHOREV)` causes the QMgr to put an event message into `SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT` queue for each 2035. The SupportPacs I mentioned parse the event into human-readable format with all the diagnostics needed to resolve auths errors. It is non-invasive to the QMgr. Only possible issue is if you have a monitoring agent like Tivoli Omegamon already consuming those messages but if so then it can also tell you what they said. If the event queue has no open input handles you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just a little research on the problem.
I have faced the same problem about hour ago. I am passing the username like domain\sortoflongusername and what i see in systemlog on WSMQ server is that my username is being truncated to 12 symbols.
I'm not really familiar with hermesJMS and soapui at all (just wanted to offer it to our testers to check it out as testing platform), so maybe anyone here does know about roots of this problem.

Comment: Given that I am using the exact same libraries with QueueZee and Java code I think there is a bug on Hermes. I am not sure if you need a domain or not on login but I have only tried with username and password, no domain, and that's much less than 12 chars long so I am not sure that's the issue.

It doesn't help that you are not allowed to register on Hermes forums at the moment so there is no way to get any good help other than maybe emailing the developer.